# SAP window hidden while obtaining data

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, sap-gui

I am writing a script / program to log  into SAP GUI then just grab a few bits of data from a employee then close SAP.

This I can do already but am trying to make a fancy GUI just for that instead of clicking many windows in SAP GUI to get it...mainly because I'm lazy cant be bothered clicking a million things... Some call this innovation I think :)

I have been researching BackGroundWorker in vb.net but wouldn't this still load the window and just keep the form active and responsive while running the program?

I don't have 'admin' rights (can create and modify user accounts `su01`, `pa30`, etc.) to the server etc. so cant log into the server\database... hence running script to obtain result..

Does anyone know how I can log into SAP GUI and have it hidden while running?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this post about how to hide an external application window.
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?669210-RESOLVED-Hiding-Window-of-external-process

In this example, guys trying to start calc.exe in hidden mode.

First off all insert at the beggining of your progect

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Then you have to enum flags for ShowWindow (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
Private Enum ShowWindowCommand As Integer
    Hide = 0
    Show = 5
    Minimize = 6
    Restore = 9
End Enum
```

Set a specified window's show state

```
 <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
 Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As ShowWindowCommand) As Boolean
 End Function
```

Determine whether the specified window handle identifies an existing window

```
 <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
 Private Shared Function IsWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
 End Function
```

Determines whether a specified window is minimized.

```
 Private Declare Auto Function IsIconic Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean
```

variable to save window handle (you can choise your own name, but rename in other part of code)

```
 Private calc_hWnd As IntPtr
```

launch windows calculator (in your case saplogon.exe) minimized and hidden, while loading form

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim test As New Process
    Try
        ' file to launch            
        test.StartInfo.FileName = "calc.exe" ' note: full path not needed for windows calc.
        ' Note: This next line has no effect on WinXP "calc.exe" and some other apps like FireFox.
        'test.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized

        ' start the app
        test.Start()
        ' wait until app is in idle state
        test.WaitForInputIdle(-1)



        ' get app main window handle
        Dim tmp_hWnd As IntPtr = test.MainWindowHandle
        ' make sure handle is valid (non zero)


        ' try up to 10 times within one second
        ' do a re-try loop that runs for a second or two
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            tmp_hWnd = test.MainWindowHandle
            If Not tmp_hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then Exit For ' got handle so exit loop
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) ' wait 100ms
        Next '- try again 




        If Not tmp_hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
            ' use ShowWindow to change app window state (minimize and hide it).
            ShowWindow(tmp_hWnd, ShowWindowCommand.Minimize)
            ShowWindow(tmp_hWnd, ShowWindowCommand.Hide)
            ' save handle for later use.
            calc_hWnd = tmp_hWnd
        Else
            ' no window handle?
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to get a window handle!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' error !
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

on exit restore/unhide app if found running.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    ' is our variable set to non-zero?
    If Not calc_hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        ' is app window found?
        If IsWindow(calc_hWnd) = True Then
            ' if app is minimized then restore it
            If IsIconic(calc_hWnd) Then
                ShowWindow(calc_hWnd, ShowWindowCommand.Restore)
            End If
            ' make sure window is seen incase it was hidden.
            ShowWindow(calc_hWnd, ShowWindowCommand.Show)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But you can write another code in and kill saplogon.exe process.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    For Each p As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("saplogon.exe")
        Try
            p.Kill()
            ' possibly with a timeout
            p.WaitForExit()
            ' process has already exited - might be able to let this one go

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.toString)
       End Try
    Next
End Sub
```